# How to access data in realtime from MatrikonOPC Server for simulation and testing

Tags: opc

I need help to accessing simulated data in MatrikonOPC Server from any type of client application or SQLServer.

Comment: I installed the MatrikonOPC Explorer, MatrikonOPC Server for Simulation and Testing and MatrikonOPC Client for ODBC. 
Also I tried to implement the same way in the few youtube tutorials is shown but with no success.
All I want to achieve is to have MatrikonOPC Server for Simulation and Testing generating the random data as now, but I want to be able to read that data from app (eg. ASP.NET MVC) and then show data in webpage in real-time using SignalR and Highcarts.js.
Is that possible?

Comment: What were the OPC client toolkits or other code you have tried, and what do you mean by "no success": Did you get a specific error message (post its text here...), or what were the symptoms of the problem?

Answer (score 0):

I have a really dumb example that displays one data point from an OPC DA server inside a ASP.NET page:

https://github.com/jdecuyper/OPC-DA-ASPNET-Client

This could get you started. However you should provide more details in case that is not enough.